# Opera remote devies debugging

Tags: chromium, opera, remote-debugging

Currently, Opera remote devices debugging doesn't appear to be working. It doesn't appear to discover USB devices what so ever.

I'm wondering if this is the case for everyone?

And if anyone has found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

1. Close Chrome
2. Open chrome://inspect link in Opera and enable
   debugging
3. Enjoy